# Bounty which is not in line with health SE policies

Tags: discussion, references, bounty

I'm concerned about the text that accompanies the bounty on [this question about scleroderma](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/4623/can-blood-transfusion-help-in-case-of-scleroderma). The question in it's own right is interesting, and the OP specifically asks for reliable references, but than the bounty reads:

> Scleroderma is a rare disease and so resources are quite limited. **Your opinion/thoughts might be valuable even without strong sources/background, so please do not hesitate to share it.**

(emphasis mine).

Not only is this in contradiction with health SE policy on references, but it also opposes the OP's direct request for references.

Can any action be taken to stop or change this? There is no way to flag a bounty offer, as far as I know. This one has clearly been made by a user not active on health SE, but has sufficient rep to offer a bounty due to 100 points bonus, which users get for being active on other SE sites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can flag the post as "In need of moderator intervention", and in the provided box explain why you believe it needs to be looked at.

In this case, you are correct, the bounty wording is against the OP wishes and site policy, so I removed the bounty offering.